# Inject mongoose model validation in angular view

Tags: angularjs, validation, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I am using mean stack for development. I believe that for the current and default implementation, the client (angular) need to interact to the server(mongoose) and the server return the error message that display on angular view. This means that it only covers the part for server side validation.

Is there any existing solution or any configuration that allow the mongoose model validation to be injected to angular view page so that it becomes a client side validation in addition to the server side validation? Or how could it possibly be achieved?

It seems repetitive to maintain two separate code, one in angular (for client side validation) and one in mongoose (for server side validation). Isn't it good if the mongoose validation can be injected to angular view? I believe that this is one of the feature that is most sought of but I didn't manage to find anything related to this online.

And this is not rocket science, as it has been implemented in other platform. Microsoft jquery unobstructive validation, as example, hook up the server side model validation and inject it in client view.

Answer (score 0):

I never used it but maybe [ng-schema](https://github.com/dalcib/ng-schema) could help you. But take into account that despite solving the problem of using mongoose validations within the angular form you will have to define a schema, and this can be even harder or a "not so clean" solution to maintain, because if one day you decide to update a mongoose model in the backend you will also have to update all the schemas you define in ng-schema. So the problem of managing separate codes for similar purposes still persists.

I personally prefer to use a custom validation in the angular form to handle max-lengths, required fields, etc. And after form submission to the server, let mongoose handle the logic and return possible errors to the client side.

If you're using MEAN.JS, you can edit the error handler configuration and adapt it to your needs in `modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller.js`.

Comment: but this means there is no client side validation right ??? My iniatitive was to inject mongoose validation code to client side angular view upon loading without duplicating the view.

Comment: I guess there is indeed client side validation at least according to the documentation in ng-schema github page.